# Json Array Parsing

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft to try to parse a jSON array in C# Winform solution.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

```
["yahoo!",["yahoo mail","yahoo finance","yahoo news","yahoo mail login","yahoo sports","yahoo fantasy football","yahoo fantasy","yahoo india","yahoo groups","yahoo search"]]

 string json = Helpers.GetGoogleSuggestionKeyword("Yahoo!").ToString();
            JArray GoogleSuggesionKeywordResult = JArray.Parse(json);
            foreach (JObject item in GoogleSuggesionKeywordResult)
            {
            //    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: you want read the string to json? or `Helpers.GetGoogleSuggestionKeyword("Yahoo!").ToString()' to json?

Comment: @BaskarJohn
Yes this method return the json string, how I can parse the json values?

Answer (score 0):

```
        //var json = "[\"yahoo!\",[\"yahoo mail\",\"yahoo finance\",\"yahoo news\",\"yahoo mail login\",\"yahoo sports\",\"yahoo fantasy football\",\"yahoo fantasy\",\"yahoo india\",\"yahoo groups\",\"yahoo search\"]]";
        string json = Helpers.GetGoogleSuggestionKeyword("Yahoo!").ToString();
        JArray GoogleSuggesionKeywordResult = JArray.Parse(json);
        //JArray GoogleSuggesionKeywordResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
        foreach (JToken item in GoogleSuggesionKeywordResult[1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine((string)item);
        }
```

i have used JArray & JsonConverter. Which method you preferred you can use it